# Is possible a web app that execute Pandas/Scipy/Numpy in the client?

Tags: javascript, python, html, numpy

I wrote a data processing program in python. My program takes some input data and transforms it using python libraries such as PYTHON-MIP, Numpy, Scipy, Pandas, etc. I want to build a graphical interface for this program and I would like it to be web to display graphs with libraries like Chart JS. I know how to build this app by separating the frontend and the backend. But I would like the processing to run on the client. That is, I want an application without a backend. I don't know what options I have.

Comment: There’s a Javascript library able to interpret and run Python code, if I remember correctly. It probably won’t be able to run numpy et al though, and even if it could, it’d probably not be very fast.

Answer (score 0):

The browser (the "client") is **not** able to run python code. It will have to run on the server side.

Comment: I know that. But for example, you can build a website using R with the shiny library. You can manipulate the DOM and you can also use all R libraries. All that without using javascript. My question is if there is an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

With web assembly is possible execute python in the client. The best option is pyodide, that able the numpy, scipy, scikitlearn, pandas, etc. [Pyodide](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/)